# Track compilation time of user controls and pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dynamic-compilation

Using pre and post build tasks in Visual Studio 2010, I can record compilation time through the day. I'd like to do the same with dynamically compiled user controls and pages, to monitor what happens in `Temporary ASP.NET`.

Should I create a custom C# compiler that calls the "real" compiler, with log output before/after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a "custom" compiler and referencing it from the web.config seems to be a way.

*I'm now stuck with weird behavior:* [LINQ-related error when using simple CSharpCodeProvider in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13458605/446576)