# LINQ-related error when using simple CSharpCodeProvider in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web-config, csharpcodeprovider

I've created a very simple custom compiler:

```
public class SimpleCompiler : CSharpCodeProvider
{
    public SimpleCompiler() : base()
    {
        File.AppendText("d:\foo.txt","bar");
    }
}
```

In my web.config file, I copied/pasted existing configuration to declare this new compiler.

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="XXX.SimpleCompiler, XXX" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
</compiler>
```

But I get errors when accessing user controls with code like:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3">
    <%# 
         string.Join("<br/>",((ReadOnlyCollection<AAA>)Eval("ListOfAs")).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray())                                 
    %>
 </asp:Label>
```

It fails on `>` of `<AAA>`. Something should be missing somewhere (using?), but it builds fine with standard compiler `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`.

Error message is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'

**Update:** It seems to be related to LINQ. It fails on all pages with LINQ in control code. However System.Core.dll is included in Web.config.

**Update2:** I was able to reproduce it in a new Web Application project.

1. Add a new class:

   ```
   namespace WebApplication1
   {
       public class SimpleCompiler : CSharpCodeProvider
       {
           private void Log(string message)
           {
               File.AppendAllText("d:\\foo.txt", DateTime.Now.Ticks+Environment.NewLine);
           } 
      }
   ```

   }
2. Update `web.config`

   ```
   <system.codedom>
       <compilers>
         <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="WebApplication1.SimpleCompiler, WebApplication1">
             <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
             <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
           </compiler>
       </compilers>
   </system.codedom>
   ```
3. change `Default.aspx` to:

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head runat="server"></head>
       <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <div>
               <%
                   int x = (new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }).Where(z => z > 2).Count();
                   this.Response.Write(x);
               %>
           </div>
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

If I update project to `4.0`, it works. But I can't do that in other one.

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing around `x => x ...`?

Comment: Are you referencing CSharpCodeProvider from .NET 2?

Comment: Can you demonstrate this *without* using ASP.NET, e.g. from a simple console app?

Comment: Code is working fine if I use "default" compiler thus I'm pretty sure `x => x` is OK. I'm using .NET 3.5. But I can't figure out how to test it outside Asp.NET: most of pages build fine, and only such code is broken.

Comment: @SimonMourier, DLL info: `Assembly System.dll, v2.0.50727`

Comment: I have tested this with a VS2010 web project, and it works fine for me (my compiler class resides in a C# in the web project). Can you post a repro project somewhere?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't (company project). For now my compiler class is in another project. I'll try your way.

Comment: Please have a look at my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try add to Web.config:

```
<pages>
   <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Linq" />
   </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and

```
<compilation>
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: @FrancoisB: And absolutely the same code is being compiled fine with default C# compiler, correct?

Comment: Right. Only Linq expressions fail to build.